# Prompt for information multiple times

Tags: java, iteration, user-input

I am new to programming and I'm writing a simple robot in java to split PDF documents and save them to a file.  AS of right now my program asks how many slips (PDF documents) there are and then it asks how many pages there are.  The problem is that it only asks how many pages once.  I need it to ask how many pages are in each individual slip.  First I tried to wrap the JOption statement in an if statement but then the variable was out of scope.  So I made a method for each question, one for number of slips and one for the amount of pages.  I obviously still have the same result.  Can you please help me out?

Here is my code

```
//RES. 1366 x 768
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class automation 
{
Robot robot = new Robot();
public static void main(String [] args) throws AWTException
{
    new automation();
}
public automation() throws AWTException 
{
    int medDelay = 200;
    int counter2 = 1;
    int slips = slips();
    int pages = pages();
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    while (counter2 <= slips)
    {

    counter2 = counter2 + 1;

    //move to file in bridge and double click opens file
    robot.delay(3000);
    robot.mouseMove(300, 150);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    //maximize reader window
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);

    robot.delay(medDelay);
    //move to tools hit enter
    robot.mouseMove(1190, 100);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    //move to text recognition and click
    robot.mouseMove(1190, 275);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    //scroll down to in this file click and press enter
    robot.mouseMove(1190, 320);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);  
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    //move to book marks and click
    robot.delay(60000);
    robot.mouseMove(10, 170);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    //move to patient name and triple click
    int counter1 = 1;
    while(counter1 <= pages){
    //JOptionPane.showInputDialog("You are on page " + i + "." );
    counter1 = counter1+1;
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mouseMove(335, 200);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);  
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    //move to create book mark and click
    robot.mouseMove(180, 175);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mouseMove(50, 100);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are on page " + i + "." );
    }
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);  
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mouseMove(10, 170);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mouseMove(1190, 275);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mouseMove(1190, 100);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(medDelay);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Q);  
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.mouseMove(300, 150);
    robot.delay(300);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.delay(300);
    robot.mouseMove(50, 315);
    robot.delay(500);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

    }
}
private int slips() {
    String slips = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many slips are there?");
    int slip = Integer.parseInt(slips);
    return slip;
}
private int pages() {
    String pages = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many pages are there?");
    int page = Integer.parseInt(pages);
    return page;
}


}
```

Comment: This is going to get closed. Specific problems is what SO is for, design ideas, recommendations, etc., are done elsewhere.

Comment: You are looking for "iteration". You will need to invoke showInputDialog() from within some kind of loop - probably `while`, as in "while there are still files left...".

Comment: @Rob While this might indeed get closed, I have no idea where you get the notion that this problem is "not specific." If anything, it would get closed because it's a code dump and possibly a candidate for "a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error". The description at the top is actually sufficient to provide a current and desired behavior; there's even some things the OP tried! The only thing missing is a shorter example.

Comment: Yeah you are probably right. I thought the OP was asking for opinions about approach etc.

Comment: @WAF I have no idea how your suggested edit got approved, but your title change makes *far* too many assumptions about the nature of the problem. The title no longer reflects the problem; it reflects what you think is the OP's misunderstanding. I'm still trying to come up with a good title to replace it.

Comment: Thanks for all the input.  Sorry if I did not post this correctly.  I will look into itteration.

Comment: @jpmc26 I guess I just misunderstood the question's intent, but wanted to bring the title and tags more to the point. Thanks for carrying on that effort.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get more help if your code is readable. You won't get/keep a programming position these days with variable names like, m,l,j and t....  Please, consider the maintenance programmer.

That said,  you're probably looking for something in this vein:

```
int slips = slips();
int outterCounter = 1; 
while (outterCounter <= slips)
{
    int pages = pages();
    int innerCounter = 1;
    while (innerCounter <= pages)
    {
        // your logic
       innerCounter++;
    }

    outterCounter++;
}
```

**Edit**: OP had it originally as 1 based...

Comment: Thanks ill check into it.

Comment: If it answers your question, please remember to mark it as answered...  Note too, that I initialized your variable to 0, but did not change the comparison (to less than).  I changed it back to 1 to align with your example. -S